# Convention for declaring structs in C

Tags: c, coding-style, conventions

Consider the following C struct:

```
struct person {
    char *name;
    unsigned int age;
};
```

In many samples of C code that I have recently come across, I have seen structs instead declared in the following manner:

```
typedef struct {
    char *name;
    unsigned int age;
} person_t;
```

Other than brevity in that a declaration can then be made as `person_t bob` rather than `struct person bob`, is there any advantage to doing this? Furthermore, what is the standard convention within the C community for when do declare a struct the normal way versus when to declare it within a typedef?

Comment: The suffix `_t` is reserved for standardisation use only.